# CSS style for certain UL and LI tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hey all I always have the worst time trying to get my CSS to play nice. I have some code that makes use of `ul` and also `li` tags. However, I am wanting to only put that style on a few parts of my HTML code and not all of the `ul` and `li` tags.

There's other style sheets that use `li` and `ul` as well and its currently clashing with this style I am wanting to use.

This is my code for both tags:

```
ul {
    position: relative;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;       
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
       -moz-perspective: 400px;
        -ms-perspective: 400px;
         -o-perspective: 400px;
            perspective: 400px;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    background: #eee;
    color: #252525;
    font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
       -moz-transform: translateZ(0px);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
         -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
            transform: translateZ(0px);
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff;
}

ul .locationList li.cache {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(1deg);
}
```

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div id="listBG" style="margin-bottom: 40px; line-height: 1; background-image:url(file:///C|/Users/Pictures/googleMapsZoom.JPG)">
 <ul class="flip" style="height: 568px; overflow: hidden;">
  <li id="locationListClick" style="opacity: 1;">
    <div id="distance" style="font-size:12px;float: right;">
      Distance: 13 mi.<br />
      <div align="center">
         <img src="getDirectionsAndroid.png" width="74" height="53" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="place" style="font-size:12px;margin: 0px; line-height: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
         The Choo Choo</p>
    <p id="address" style="font-size:12px;margin: 0px;line-height: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
       100 A Street, ChooChoo, GA 76859<br /></p>
    <p id="dates" style="font-size:12px;margin: 5px;line-height: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
       Event Date(s) &amp; Time(s):<br /></p>
    <p id="dates" style="font-size:12px;margin-top: -5px; margin-left: 10px;line-height: 15px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
       01/23/2015 @ 3:00<br /></p>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```css
div#listBG ul {}
```

This above works fine for the `ul`

```css
div#listBG ul li {}
```

But this above doesn't seem to work for both `ul` with `li`?

Comment: What does *doesn't seem to work* mean?   Also, you have inline styles in your HTML that will override anything you put in your stylesheet.

Comment: consider using classes to style ul and li.

Comment: you should not use inline styles, instead use classes or ID's for your selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of classes in your css sheet. In my example, I will call them "class_a" and "class_b"

CSS:

```
.class_a {
    margin: 0,0,0,0;
}

.class_b {
    margin: 1,1,1,1;
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="class_a">
    <!--item here-->
</li>
```

Classes allow you to have multiple styles when using the same tag.